# What is the use of "domain" attribute when we create a custom translation model

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

After reading the [docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/language-translator?topic=language-translator-customizing) regarding creation of custom translation model it is not clear what is the use of the **domain** attribute when we create a IBM Cloud Translation custom translation model ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/language-translator?topic=language-translator-customizing)

> Most of the provided translation models in Language Translator can be
> extended to learn custom terms and phrases or a **general** style that's
> derived from your translation data. Follow these instructions to
> create your own custom translation model.
>
> Use a parallel corpus when you want your custom model to learn from
> **general** translation patterns in parallel sentences in your samples.
> What your model learns from a parallel corpus can improve translation
> results for input text that the model has not been trained on. You can
> upload multiple parallel corpora files with a request. To successfully
> train with parallel corpora, the corpora files must contain a
> cumulative total of at least 5000 parallel sentences. The cumulative
> size of all uploaded corpus files for a custom model is limited to 250
> MB.

Check the [customizing your model](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/language-translator?topic=language-translator-customizing#supported-document-formats-for-training-data) documentation for more info.

*Make sure that your Language Translator service instance is on an Advanced or Premium pricing plan.*